When are Hurwitz Zeta's polynomials of each other?
For $z\in \mathbb{C}$, let $$e_1(z) = \frac 1 z + \sum_{n\geq 1} \left(\frac 1 {z+n} + \frac 1 {z-n}\right)$$
and for $k\geq 2$,
$$e_k(z) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} \frac 1 {(z+n)^k}.$$
These $e_k$ are meromorphic, 1-periodic functions which satisfy $e_1(z)=\pi \cot(\pi z)$ and $e_k'=-ke_{k+1}$.
Given that $e_2(z)=\frac {\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)}$ we have the relation
$$-e_1'=e_2=e_1^2+\pi^2\quad (*)$$
which implies that every $e_k$ is a polynomial in $e_1$. It's a simple inductive argument, falling from the fact that when differentiating a polynomial in $e_1$ you "pick up" an $e_1'$ which by $(*)$ is again a polynomial in $e_1$.
Let's compute $(e_2')^2$ and $e_2''$. This comes down to calculating $e_3^2$ and $e_4$. Given that $$e_3=-\frac 1 2 e_2'=e_2e_1$$
we get $$e_3^2 = e_2^2(e_2-\pi^2)$$
and similarly $e_4=e_2^2-\frac 23\pi^2e_2$. Therefore

$e_k$ is a polynomial in $e_2$ for all even $k\geq 1$.

I'd like there to be a pattern. So I ask:

Is $e_m$ always a polynomial in $e_n$ if $n$ divides $m$?

Note: as we have seen, it would be enough to show that, for all $i_1,\ldots,i_r\in\{n+1,\ldots,m\}$ that sum up to $m$,
$$e_{i_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot e_{i_r}$$
is a polynomial in $e_n$.
This does not work as $e_4e_2$ is not a polynomial in $e_3$. Indeed, we have
$$e_4 = \frac 23 e_2e_1^2 + \frac 13 e_2^2$$
Hence $e_4e_2= e_3^2 + \frac {\pi^2}{3}e_2^2$ (skipped over the details). If $e_2e_4$ were a polynomial in $e_3$, so would be $e_2^2$, but the latter has a pole of order 4 at 0 which is not divisible by 3, leading to a contradiction.
So this tells me that if the claim to be true then it must not be straightforward to show. Before crunching through the expression of $e_6$, do any of you have a hint to (dis)prove this fact?
